# WGCNA sharing namespaces for statistical methods

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm using a function from the `WGCNA` package that has a parameter corType which takes a string input of the specific correlation you want to run. Two of the main correlation methods are "pearson" and "bicor". When I run the function I get an error when the function gets to processing the corType parameter. If I run "pearson" I get the error:

```r
Error in (function(x, y - NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", unused arguments (weights.x = NULL, weights.y = NULL,
cosine = FALSE)
```

If I run the function with corType as "bicor" I get the error:

```r
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'bicor' of mode 'function' was not found
```

I did some searching on biostars and it seemed like `WGCNA` was running into a shared namespace problem. An old post suggested that I do one of two things:

1. Restart R and only load the `WGCNA` package before running the function (which seems silly, since I might run the function several times in a day.)
2. Set the cor namespace to that of `WGCNA` (via `WGCNA::cor`) and then resetting it back to the default `stat` package (via `stat::cor`). Which seems better but might still be clunky.

Below I have tried to include a minimally reproducible example as well as my R session info. It's probably important to mention that I'm building a package so when I run the WGCNA functions its within another function and instead of using `require()` for each package I add them to the imports in the `DESCRIPTION` and call a function within those packages using `foo::bar`. I have run the following code in my own R environment and duplicated the errors. Please let me know if you need any further in formation.

```r
cnames = c("GSM2886523", "GSM2886524", "GSM2886525", "GSM2886526", "GSM2886527")
test.expr.data <- matrix(c(0.1708434,-0.1129639,-0.09490149,-0.08757270,0.08918957, 
                           0.9866739,-1.0146009,-2.18310607,-1.92989284,-2.01153493, 
                           -0.1447803,0.2311808,-0.09179321,-0.16356002,-0.19043491, 
                           -0.2162092,0.2822163,0.06230056,-0.03903165,0.53407426, 
                           -0.2659731,0.1810084,0.02749196,-0.07015478,-0.07480163), 
                           nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
colnames(test.expr.data) <- cnames

wgcna_out = WGCNA::blockwiseModules(t(expr_data), power = 5, networkType = "signed", 
                                    corType = "pearson")
#Error in (function(x, y - NULL, use = "everything", method = c("pearson", unused arguments (weights.x = NULL, weights.y = NULL,
#cosine = FALSE)

wgcna_out = WGCNA::blockwiseModules(t(expr_data), power = 5, networkType = "signed", 
                                    corType = "bicor")
#Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
#  object 'bicor' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Should I set and then reset the cor namespace each time I run this function or is there a more elegant way to do work around this problem?

[image: R session info.]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Don't just show the error, show the code you were running to get the error as well. What other packages do you have loaded?

Comment: I would consider this as a bug in WGCNA. Without a reproducible example and limited time I am somewhat discouraged from going down the rabbit hole and finding a definitive solution but the root of the issue is their `.corFnc` variable where functions are named without explicitly calling their namespace. I believe changing `.corFnc` to `c("WGCNA::cor", "WGCNA::bicor", "WGCNA::cor")` would solve the issue but there might be downstream errors since I see a few examples of string matching in their code. String matching seems to be done on `.corTypes` so it could be an easy fix.

Comment: The problematic file is `internalConstants.R`. You can get a clone of WGCNA from `https://github.com/cran/WGCNA`. If a fix is found, WGCNA people should probably be told about it. Will stop by later myself if I have the time

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful comments! I've updated my question to be a little more helpful to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware of this problem; at present I simply use

```
cor=WGCNA::cor
```

before I run WGCNA code.

I'll have to check on the bicor problem, that should not happen.

Comment: Your solution works great for the pearson option but the error for bicor is still thrown.

Comment: sholdn't doing `bicor = WGCNA::bicor` should fix that one

Comment: What do you see when you type `bicor`?